# c#.net web service

Tags: c#, service

i want to create a simple webservice , and i want to call that webservice from a client program using c#.net. As i am a beginner, i find it difficult to do it. can anybody help.

Thank you...

Comment: You could try this: ( http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/myservice.aspx )

Comment: @Michael .. and she can use google...!!

Comment: @jjj That was sort of my point...I was trying to be helpful but also nudge the OP in the right direction.

Comment: @Michael ..ya... actualy i was going to do the same thing..but you were faster ..hahah..^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a file with extension asmx. Provide your function that is to be exposed, as a [WebMethod].

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return "Hello World";
}
```

from your other application add a web reference to the currently built asmx page. From that reference you will be able to invoke the desired function.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just learning about web services, I'd recommend against going the ASMX/`WebService`/`WebMethod` route.  That functionality has been superseded by WCF.

[WCF Getting Started Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx)

[WCF 101](http://blogs.msdn.com/youssefm/archive/2009/11/02/wcf-101-the-simplest-wcf-example-you-ll-ever-see.aspx) (very simple example)

Comment: are the above statement still stood valid as today?

Comment: @Roylee: Nothing has superseded WCF as of today; and ASMX is obviously even **more** obsolete today than it was nearly 4 years ago. Don't use it, unless you enjoy hearing your work referred to as "legacy code".

Comment: Thank you @Aaronaught, for the reply. Given the fact that I am a complete beginner to web services, and I would like to explore this technology on .NET. In your opinion, what are the directions that I should have headed? In specific, I would like to understand the foundations, which would eventually leads to Restful, WSDL, etc... in .NET =) Please correct me if I'm wrong of expecting Restful and WSDL as the implementation of web services.

Comment: @Roylee: WSDL has very little to do with REST, and a comment thread really isn't the place to be giving a tutorial on distributed architecture, sorry. Ask another question, probably on [programmers.se] if it's very general, but try to do some of your own research first. Looking up what [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP), and [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) actually are would be a start. REST is generally exposed over pure HTTP, not an abstraction like SOAP.

Comment: Alright, I felt that's is very helpful already =) Thanks @Aaronaught. I was thinking that if there is any good books on these.

Answer (score 0):

There are several tutorial you can look at and learn from:

1. http://www.codeguru.com/Csharp/Csharp/cs_webservices/tutorials/article.php/c5477
2. http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dotnetwebservices/DotNetWebServices.asp
3. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wbhsy70.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm basically in a same situation as you, so I'll share what I've thought of so far. I haven't really implemented anything like you described yet (just a simple web app), so consider this a thought experiment and the preliminary results of my research.

To create the web service, I thought using **[Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/)** would be the easiest thing to do. It's free, and pretty easy to understand and use even for a beginner. They have a lot of tutorials too. Their datastore is also easy to use. You have to write your code in Python + Django templates or Java, and although I had never used python or django before, I found them amazingly quick and easy to learn the basics. There's also an Eclipse plugin for it.

From what I've seen, you create a structure of URLs to your resources (the data you want to access from your web service. For example /planets/earth. You map these URLs to WebRequestHandlers in your google apps code. In your code, you "handle" a message from some client through one of the HTTP methods like GET or POST. Depending on the method, you perform some programming task to prepare the data and then send back a response. For example, maybe you set it up so that you return the diameter of earth when you someone GETs /planets/earth.

Then, in your application you can send and receive stuff from your web service using **[System.Net.HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)**. This is the part I have never done, but I think you just create and instance of HttpWebRequest, give it the appropriate info like URL, Method, data to send, etc, then send the web request on it's way. You get the response and do something with it in your program.

Well, that's an overview of what I've found so far, and I hope it's helpful (and not wrong)!

Answer (score 0):

```html
  [WebMethod]
        public string LatinicaUCirilicu(string latin)
        {
            string rec = "";
            string slovo;
            string duplo;

            for (int i = 0; i < latin.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i < latin.Length - 1)
                {
                    duplo = latin.Substring(i, 2);
                    switch (duplo)
                    {
                        case "lj": rec += "љ"; i++; break;
                        case "LJ": rec += "Љ"; i++; break;
                        case "Lj": rec += "Љ"; i++; break;
                        case "lJ": rec += "љ"; i++; break;
                        case "nj": rec += "њ"; i++; break;
                        case "NJ": rec += "Њ"; i++; break;
                        case "Nj": rec += "Њ"; i++; break;
                        case "nJ": rec += "њ"; i++; break;
                        case "dž": rec += "џ"; i++; break;
                        case "DŽ": rec += "Џ"; i++; break;
                        case "Dž": rec += "Џ"; i++; break;
                        case "dŽ": rec += "џ"; i++; break;
                        default: slovo = Convert.ToString(latin[i]);
                            switch (slovo)
                            {
                                case "a": rec += "a"; break;
                                case "b": rec += "б"; break;
                                case "c": rec += "ц"; break;
                                case "č": rec += "ч"; break;
                                case "ć": rec += "ћ"; break;
                                case "d": rec += "д"; break;
                                case "đ": rec += "ђ"; break;
                                case "e": rec += "е"; break;
                                case "f": rec += "ф"; break;
                                case "g": rec += "г"; break;
                                case "h": rec += "х"; break;
                                case "i": rec += "и"; break;
                                case "j": rec += "ј"; break;
                                case "k": rec += "к"; break;
                                case "l": rec += "л"; break;
                                case "m": rec += "м"; break;
                                case "n": rec += "н"; break;
                                case "o": rec += "о"; break;
                                case "p": rec += "п"; break;
                                case "r": rec += "р"; break;
                                case "s": rec += "с"; break;
                                case "š": rec += "ш"; break;
                                case "t": rec += "т"; break;
                                case "u": rec += "у"; break;
                                case "v": rec += "в"; break;
                                case "z": rec += "з"; break;
                                case "ž": rec += "ж"; break;
                                case "A": rec += "А"; break;
                                case "B": rec += "Б"; break;
                                case "C": rec += "Ц"; break;
                                case "Č": rec += "Ч"; break;
                                case "Ć": rec += "Ћ"; break;
                                case "D": rec += "Д"; break;
                                case "Đ": rec += "Ђ"; break;
                                case "E": rec += "Е"; break;
                                case "F": rec += "Ф"; break;
                                case "G": rec += "Г"; break;
                                case "H": rec += "Х"; break;
                                case "I": rec += "И"; break;
                                case "J": rec += "Ј"; break;
                                case "K": rec += "К"; break;
                                case "L": rec += "Л"; break;
                                case "M": rec += "М"; break;
                                case "N": rec += "Н"; break;
                                case "O": rec += "О"; break;
                                case "P": rec += "П"; break;
                                case "R": rec += "Р"; break;
                                case "S": rec += "С"; break;
                                case "Š": rec += "Ш"; break;
                                case "T": rec += "Т"; break;
                                case "U": rec += "У"; break;
                                case "V": rec += "В"; break;
                                case "Z": rec += "З"; break;
                                case "Ž": rec += "Ж"; break;
                                default: rec += slovo; break;
                            } break;
                    }
                }
                if (i == latin.Length - 1)
                {
                    slovo = Convert.ToString(latin[i]);
                    switch (slovo)
                    {
                        case "a": rec += "a"; break;
                        case "b": rec += "б"; break;
                        case "c": rec += "ц"; break;
                        case "č": rec += "ч"; break;
                        case "ć": rec += "ћ"; break;
                        case "d": rec += "д"; break;
                        case "đ": rec += "ђ"; break;
                        case "e": rec += "е"; break;
                        case "f": rec += "ф"; break;
                        case "g": rec += "г"; break;
                        case "h": rec += "х"; break;
                        case "i": rec += "и"; break;
                        case "j": rec += "ј"; break;
                        case "k": rec += "к"; break;
                        case "l": rec += "л"; break;
                        case "m": rec += "м"; break;
                        case "n": rec += "н"; break;
                        case "o": rec += "о"; break;
                        case "p": rec += "п"; break;
                        case "r": rec += "р"; break;
                        case "s": rec += "с"; break;
                        case "š": rec += "ш"; break;
                        case "t": rec += "т"; break;
                        case "u": rec += "у"; break;
                        case "v": rec += "в"; break;
                        case "z": rec += "з"; break;
                        case "ž": rec += "ж"; break;
                        case "A": rec += "А"; break;
                        case "B": rec += "Б"; break;
                        case "C": rec += "Ц"; break;
                        case "Č": rec += "Ч"; break;
                        case "Ć": rec += "Ћ"; break;
                        case "D": rec += "Д"; break;
                        case "Đ": rec += "Ђ"; break;
                        case "E": rec += "Е"; break;
                        case "F": rec += "Ф"; break;
                        case "G": rec += "Г"; break;
                        case "H": rec += "Х"; break;
                        case "I": rec += "И"; break;
                        case "J": rec += "Ј"; break;
                        case "K": rec += "К"; break;
                        case "L": rec += "Л"; break;
                        case "M": rec += "М"; break;
                        case "N": rec += "Н"; break;
                        case "O": rec += "О"; break;
                        case "P": rec += "П"; break;
                        case "R": rec += "Р"; break;
                        case "S": rec += "С"; break;
                        case "Š": rec += "Ш"; break;
                        case "T": rec += "Т"; break;
                        case "U": rec += "У"; break;
                        case "V": rec += "В"; break;
                        case "Z": rec += "З"; break;
                        case "Ž": rec += "Ж"; break;
                        default: rec += slovo; break;
                    } break;
                }

                
            }
            return rec;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public string CirilicaULatinicu(string ciril)
        {
            string rec = "";
            string slovo;
            for (int i = 0; i < ciril.Length; i++)
            {
                slovo = Convert.ToString(ciril[i]);
                switch (slovo)
                {
                    case "а": rec += "a"; break;
                    case "б": rec += "b"; break;
                    case "ц": rec += "c"; break;
                    case "ч": rec += "č"; break;
                    case "ћ": rec += "ć"; break;
                    case "д": rec += "d"; break;
                    case "џ": rec += "dž"; break;
                    case "ђ": rec += "đ"; break;
                    case "е": rec += "e"; break;
                    case "ф": rec += "f"; break;
                    case "г": rec += "g"; break;
                    case "х": rec += "h"; break;
                    case "и": rec += "i"; break;
                    case "ј": rec += "j"; break;
                    case "к": rec += "k"; break;
                    case "л": rec += "l"; break;
                    case "љ": rec += "lj"; break;
                    case "м": rec += "m"; break;
                    case "н": rec += "n"; break;
                    case "њ": rec += "nj"; break;
                    case "о": rec += "o"; break;
                    case "п": rec += "p"; break;
                    case "р": rec += "r"; break;
                    case "с": rec += "s"; break;
                    case "ш": rec += "š"; break;
                    case "т": rec += "t"; break;
                    case "у": rec += "u"; break;
                    case "в": rec += "v"; break;
                    case "з": rec += "z"; break;
                    case "ж": rec += "ž"; break;
                    case "А": rec += "A"; break;
                    case "Б": rec += "B"; break;
                    case "Ц": rec += "C"; break;
                    case "Ч": rec += "Č"; break;
                    case "Ћ": rec += "Ć"; break;
                    case "Д": rec += "D"; break;
                    case "Џ": rec += "Dž"; break;
                    case "Ђ": rec += "Đ"; break;
                    case "Е": rec += "E"; break;
                    case "Ф": rec += "F"; break;
                    case "Г": rec += "G"; break;
                    case "Х": rec += "H"; break;
                    case "И": rec += "I"; break;
                    case "Ј": rec += "J"; break;
                    case "К": rec += "K"; break;
                    case "Л": rec += "L"; break;
                    case "Љ": rec += "Lj"; break;
                    case "М": rec += "M"; break;
                    case "Н": rec += "N"; break;
                    case "Њ": rec += "Nj"; break;
                    case "О": rec += "O"; break;
                    case "П": rec += "P"; break;
                    case "Р": rec += "R"; break;
                    case "С": rec += "S"; break;
                    case "Ш": rec += "Š"; break;
                    case "Т": rec += "T"; break;
                    case "У": rec += "U"; break;
                    case "В": rec += "V"; break;
                    case "З": rec += "Z"; break;
                    case "Ж": rec += "Ž"; break;
                    default: rec += slovo; break;
                }
            }
            return rec;
        }
    } 
}
//    try
//    {
//        Service1 prevod = new Service1();

//        string rezultat = prevod.LatinicaUCirilicu(TextBox1.Text);
//        Label3.Text = rezultat;

//        TextBox2.Text = "";
//        Label4.Text = "";
//    }
//    catch (Exception ex)
//    {
//        Response.Write(ex.Message);
//    }
//}

//protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
//{
//    try
//    {
//        Service1 prevod = new Service1();

//        string rezultat = prevod.CirilicaULatinicu(TextBox2.Text);
//        Label4.Text = rezultat;

//        TextBox1.Text = "";
//        Label3.Text = "";
//    }
//    catch (Exception ex)
//    {
//        Response.Write(ex.Message);
//    }
//}
```

Comment: please exlpain your answer